# facebook user_id returning 0 always

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please someone help me. I trying this  almost 1 month ...  i want to retrieve the message and data. Im using the latest FB API, I tried my best I couldn't find whats wrong on it.Also I cant retreive **user_id**  .. Do I need do anything on call back function?

App url : https://apps.facebook.com/greetingz/

this is my whole code

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    require_once('src/facebook.php');

    $config = array();
    $config["appId"] = "XXXXXXXX";
    $config["secret"] = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $config["fileUpload"] = false; // optional

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $config["appId"],
      'secret' => $config["secret"],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

        $user_id= $facebook->getUser();

    if($user_id){
      try {

            $app_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

            $requests = explode(',',$_REQUEST['request_ids']);
            foreach($requests as $request_id) {

            $data = $facebook -> api('/'.$user_id.'/apprequests?'.$app_token);

            //you will delete the request here
            $delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$request_id."_".$user_id."?".$app_token."&method=delete";
            $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
        }

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }else{
    ?>

    <script>
      var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
      oauth_url += '?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX';
      oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/greetingz/');
      oauth_url += '&scope=user_birthday,user_events'
      window.top.location = oauth_url;
    </script>

    <?php
    };
    }

    else{


    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title>Greetings</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div align="center">
      <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="664" height="626">
        <param name="movie" value="flash/Candle_jey.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
        <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. -->
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
        <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/Candle_jey.swf" width="664" height="626">
          <!--<![endif]-->
          <param name="quality" value="high" />
          <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
          <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
          <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
          <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
          <div>
            <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
          </div>
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>

    </div>
    <div class="main">

    <div style="margin-left:300px; width:540px; margin:auto;">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="font-size:18px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#603;">Greeting :</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" id="msg" style="height:40px; width:350px;" ></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="one" style="color:#CCC; background-color:#603; border:none; width:80px; height:40px;"
            onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>      

    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        oauth: true
      });


      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {

        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: $("#msg").val(),

        },function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
            FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
             });
        }, requestCallback);
      }  

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
        //var requestID = FB.api("/requestID", callback);   
        alert("Post was published.");
      }
    </script>

    <div id="fb">

    </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is my whole code. Please help someone..

Comment: $user_id= $facebook->getUser(); is always returning 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buddy read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) in detail, it will solve your problem, you need to parse signed_request, in signed_request you get the user_id, you can get signed request like this authResponse.signed_request

Alternatively you can use below Facebook graph api method in place of this line "$user_id= $facebook->getUser();" in your code.

```
FB.login(function(loginResponse) {
    if (loginResponse.authResponse) {
        var userId = loginResponse.authResponse.userID;

        // Work with userId here
        var signed_request = loginResponse.authResponse.signedRequest;
        //Work with signed request here
    }
    else {
        //User cancelled login or did not fully authorize        
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried my best but I cudn't. If I give my Facebook login(Its created for the sake of a sample app) and FTP , can u check and tel. Coz I have stucke in this almost 3 weeks. Please..

Comment: Thank you very much I tried and fixed it at last. Thanks for Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Wazan, I'm having the same problem. How did you fix it?